# How to access methods of fragment class in MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have fragment class in which I'm making an `Async` call. Now I'm making a method in Fragment class and I want this method to be invoked in `MainActivity` class. The `MainActivity` class dynamically loads the `Fragment` class.

The code snippets are :

```
public class MainHandlerFragment extends Fragment{

   public boolean getDetails(User user){
      if(user==null)
         return false;
      else 
         return true;
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

I am calling

```
 MainHandlerFragment fragment = new MainHandlerFragment(user);
   fragment.getDetails();   // But i am getting NullPointerException.
```

How to invoke the method of fragment class in MainActivity?

Comment: I don't see you passing any argument to `getDetails`...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = “MyFragment.TAG”;

    // Implementation follows.

}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public MyFragment getMyFragment() {
        final FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        return (MyFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag(MyFragment.TAG);
    }

    public void invokeMethodFromMyFragment() {
        final MyFragment fragment = getMyFragment();
        if (null != fragment) {
            fragment.getDetails();
        }
    }

}
```

This assumes your `MyFragment` transaction included the `MyFragment.TAG` tag when commited.

Comment: ok.. If i want to pass one object from Fragment to MainActivity how can i do that.. For ex User object i am passing from fragment to MainActivity @curtisLoew

Comment: Read [the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanx..@curtisLeow. Really documentation part was very helpful and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentClass fragment = (FragmentClass) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.ll_fragment1);
        fragment.fragmentMethod();
```

try this in your activity you can call the method of fragment from your activity

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the

```
fragment.getDetail(user);
```

after completing the Transaction using add() or replace() method of the Transaction Class .... and the commit() it also.

Hope it will work.